# How to restrict certain files on apache to authenticated users?

Tags: php, apache, security, authentication, post

In a site which uses a normal, cookie-based authentication where the password is stored on a cookie, is there a way to serve files only for users that are already logged in?

Comment: Storing the password in the cookie : **wrong idea**

Comment: apache doesn't work cookies directly. it's easy enough to test for the PRESENCE of a cookie, but dealing with the values in that cookie, not so much. Go with the usual method of having a script serve up the files and do the authentication/verification in the script.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV sorry I'm not a PHP dev - could you tell-me what is the right way to authenticate a user?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You can write an authenticated application where the user has to login and then the application manages the compilation of headers and whatnot for the user to access a given file. For instance, if your users need to download a PDF or something you can send pdf headers and then send binary data; they won't be able to see what file on the server you're serving up. Downside is that this is slower than just pushing them a file from the filesystem or a CDN.

Also, don't store the password in the cookie. Create a hash or something you can access and validate again, but password in cookie is just a bad idea; those guys are plaintext!